# How to detect which class to cast to when using Jackson's polymorphic deserialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

In [Programmer Bruce's example](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) for polymorphic deserialization with jackson, example 4: the object you get back is

```
class Zoo  
{  
  public Collection<Animal> animals;  
}
```

How do I know which class to cast the `Animal` object to? The `type` property is null if I add that field to the `Zoo` class. Is there a way to get that `type` property, or some how know which class to cast the `Animal` object to?

Comment: Why do you care what type of `Animal` it is? Use `instanceof`.

Comment: Well, I was hoping to avoid a series of if else clauses involving `instanceof`

Comment: As opposed to a series of type unsafe if else clauses involving a `type` property?

Comment: lol when you put it that way...

Comment: This kind of depends on your use case. Do you have some greater goal you are trying to reach?